# com.hcl.domino.db.model.BulkOperationException: Internal error while readDocuments

Tags: java, lotus-domino, hcl, domino-appdev-pack

I was using domino appdev pack 1.0.7 Java API in order to read document from database. Currently trying only the sample code present in the Domino AppDev Pack. Here is the code:

```
   Server server = new Server('testappdev.com.tw', 5000,
        new File("ca.crt"),
        new File("user.crt"),
        new File("user.key"),
        "",
        "",
        Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor());
   Database client = server.useDatabase("test.nsf");

   String query = "'Contact' and FirstName = 'fname'";

   List<Document> responseDocs = client.readDocuments(query).get();
```

It works fine when query has the result documents, but it got exception below when query has no result documents.

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.hcl.domino.db.model.BulkOperationException: Internal error
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.getDoneValue(AbstractFuture.java:552)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:533)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.FluentFuture$TrustedFuture.get(FluentFuture.java:84)
    at com.xred.DqlDemo.ReadIssue.main(ReadIssue.java:39)
Caused by: com.hcl.domino.db.model.BulkOperationException: Internal error
    at com.hcl.domino.db.model.Database.noteToDocuments(Database.java:1881)
    at com.hcl.domino.db.model.Database.access$000(Database.java:38)
    at com.hcl.domino.db.model.Database$1.apply(Database.java:2006)
    at com.hcl.domino.db.model.Database$1.apply(Database.java:2003)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractTransformFuture$AsyncTransformFuture.doTransform(AbstractTransformFuture.java:214)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractTransformFuture$AsyncTransformFuture.doTransform(AbstractTransformFuture.java:203)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractTransformFuture.run(AbstractTransformFuture.java:118)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors$5$1.run(MoreExecutors.java:991)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

How to prevent this error when query has no result documents?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue should be resolved in appdev pack 1.0.8 which was released yesterday.